# Grouping users by group ids in mysql, exclude specified userid from the results?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a small application that I've been tasked on, that deals with getting latest posts in a group. In this sample below, I have there is a MySQL table formatted as such:

```
groupid      userid    date_updated
1            1          [date]
1            2          [date]
2            1          [date]
2            2          [date]
2            3          [date]
...
```

How do I do an SQL statement as such as the results go out in this manner (assuming I give a `userid` with a value of 1 for example):

```
groupid      userid     date
1            2          [date]
2            2          [date]
2            3          [date]
```

These are all ordered by date.  As you may have noticed, the results do not include the provided `userid` (as the requirement is only to get users other than the supplied user ID).  In other words, show only users other than the specified user in groups where the specified user is part of.

Is it possible to do this in a single SQL statement?

Comment: Some records have apparently disappeared in your sample output.  What is happening there?

Comment: Hi Tim, the records returned here from the sql would exclude results in which user_id was supplied.

Comment: what doesn't 'exclude' mean? I didn't get this from your question description.

Comment: Hi Dylan, I edited the question above and found an answer that sort of answered the requirement of the program.

Comment: Please don't put an answer into your question. Create a proper answer for that instead. It has very good reasons to do that.

Comment: Thank you Dawid.  I edited the question to move the answer to the proper section

Answer (score 1):

Search select query with where

```
select * from table where userid != '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution.

```
select 
    tbl.*
from 
    tbl INNER JOIN
    (select groupid, userid, max(date_updated)
     from tbl
     group by groupid, userid) tbl2
    USING(groupid, userid)
ORDER BY tbl.date_updated;
```

Comment: You're missing the input

Comment: The one assumed in the question

Comment: I am a little confused now about what PO expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT tbl.* FROM (SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY date DESC) as tbl GROUP BY tbl.groupid
```

Comment: But note that other, documented solutions are available.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a possible answer to my question here with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT a.groupid, a.userid, a.date_updated
FROM group_participants a
WHERE a.groupid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.groupid FROM group_participants b WHERE b.userid = 1
)
    AND a.user_id <> 1
GROUP BY a.userid
ORDER by a.date_updated DESC
```

Thank you guys those SQL statements you posted, gave me an idea.  I don't know if the SQL statement above can still be optimized, but this one above gave me the correct answer.